# is the parameter in @NgTwoWay("param") really does something?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have created a angular dart component "Range" that a can be used in a form.
the form is a component as well

In my code I bind the value return by the component in the form but after renaming things it seems like the parameter given to @NgTwoWay(param), in my case @NgTwoWay("v1") is not doing anything it's still mandatory though.

Here is my code:

my_form.dart

```dart
library my_form;
import "package:angular/angular.dart";

@Component(selector: "my-form", templateUrl: "my_form.html", exportExpressions: const ["submit"])
class DateFormComponent {

   @NgOneWay("random")
   bool random;

   @NgTwoWay("v1")
   String years = "eee";

   submit() {
      print(random);
      print(years);
   }

}

class DateFormModule extends Module {
   DateFormModule() {
      bind(DateFormComponent);
   }
}
```

my_form.html

```dart
<form>
   <range name="years" value="years"></range>
   <div>
      <label>Random:</label> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="random">
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Go !" ng-click="submit()">
   </div>
</form>
```

range.dart

```dart
import "package:angular/angular.dart";

@Component(selector: "range", templateUrl: "range.html")
class RangeComponent {
   @NgAttr("name")
   String name;

   @NgTwoWay("value")
   String value;

   @NgOneWay("range_begin")
   String range_begin;

   @NgOneWay("range_end")
   String range_end;

   List<String> ranges = [];

   addRange() {
      ranges.add("$range_begin-$range_end");
      range_begin = "";
      range_end = "";
      value = ranges.reduce((begin, item) {
         return begin += ",$item";
      });
   }

   info() {
      print(range_begin);
      print(range_end);
      print(ranges);
      print(value);
   }

}

class RangeComponentModule extends Module {
   RangeComponentModule() {
      bind(RangeComponent);
   }
}
```

range.html

```dart
<div>
   <label>{{name}}:</label> <input type="text" placeholder="begin"
      size="8" ng-model="range_begin"> <input type="text"
      placeholder="end" size="8" ng-model="range_end"> <input
      type="submit" value="add" ng-click="addRange()"> <input
      type="submit" value="info" ng-click="info()">
</div>
```

I thought that parameter had to bind a DOM attribute with a property of an instance ?

Answer (score 0):

You need these attributes to bind the HTML-attribute of your custom element (component) to a field of your components class.

```dart
<body ng-app>
  <my-component someattrib="somevalue"></my-component>
```

when you `MyComponent` class has a field

```dart
@NgAttr('someattrib')
String someField;
```

then 'someField' will be initialized with 'somevalue'.

You don't need such an attribute for each binding only for binding to attributes.

Comment: I understood that now but the thing is in my code there is no "v1" DOM attribute anymore and it still working !

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `it still working`. When there is no `v1` DOM attribute the `years` field can't possibly get a value from the `v1` DOM attribute assigned to it, can it?

Comment: What I want to say is : I can replace @NgTwoWay("v1") by    @NgTwoWay("whatEverTheValue") and it still working

Comment: What is still working? I'm pretty sure in this case the value from the attribute `whatEverTheValue` is not assigned to the field `years` when the attribute `whatEverTheValue` is not set ;-)

Comment: ok my bad... I removed the @NgTwoWay("v1") actually it was useless indeed... I understant a bit more the @Ngs now thx :)